# Remove the Icon and its Functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css

Goal:
When you have a lower resolution that is lower than 500 in your computer or cellphone I would like to remove the icon picture and its functionality shall not be active.

Problem:
I don't know how to do it.

Info:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sL3c1v12/14/
```

The source code is from this website `http://markgoodyear.com/labs/scrollup/`

Comment: Use media query to resolve the issue like @media screen and (min-resolution: 499dpi) { code to remove the icon... }

Comment: Sumanta - I don't know how to do it in relation to the javascript (scroll up) and @media screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change how things display depending on available screen size.

If you had an icon or image with class `.my-icon`:

```
.my-icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

You could use a media query to hide it when the available screen width is less than 500px:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .my-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you guys provide a concrete example with source code using jsfiddle to understand better?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use css media query here because it will still appear with the javascript. 
You can check the window width using javascript though like:

```
    // Ensure that only one scrollUp exists
    if (!$.data(document.body, 'scrollUp')) {
        $.data(document.body, 'scrollUp', true);
        if ($( window ).width() > 500)
            $.fn.scrollUp.init(options);
    }
```

You can see a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/sL3c1v12/21/

**Edit new fiddle**

New fiddle with onresize example: http://jsfiddle.net/sL3c1v12/32/

Use: `window.screen.width` instead for the resolution.

Comment: I tried your solution in jsfiddle but it doesn't work. Please rememeber that I would not like to change the sourcecode of scrollup inside of javascript if possible.

Comment: For me it worked (on firefox), note that it takes the window width, so perhaps you need to make the 500 bigger, or the window smaller to see it working.

Comment: It works but you need update the browser in order to be working. Is it possible to not display it by regulating the browser width size with cursor without refreshing the webpage?

Comment: What do you mean with update the browser? You can catch the resize if you need to using `window.onresize = function(event) {` and use that to hide / show the element.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is it possible to apply the new solution in jsfiddle? It is easier to understand from your perspective?

Comment: Edited my answer with the jsfiddle.